# In listing of items with checkbox make only 1 item selected

Tags: vuejs2

In vuejs 2.6 app I make listing of items with checkbox at left as 1 element must be selected, like:

```
<tr v-for="nextPersonalHostelBookmark, index in hostelBookmarks" :key="nextPersonalHostelBookmark.id">

    <td >

        <input
            type="checkbox"
            class="custom-control-input"
            id="custom_selected_personal_hostel_bookmark_id"
            name="custom_selected_personal_hostel_bookmark_id"
            v-model="selected_personal_hostel_bookmark_id"
        >
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="custom_selected_personal_hostel_bookmark_id">XX</label>
```

But if 1 elements is selected then the rest elements are selected too, that is not what I need. How can I do this 
keeping in selected_personal_hostel_bookmark_id var ID of selected element?

Comment: You should create a watch for `selected_personal_hostel_bookmark_id` and every time the length of this array goes over 1 you will `selected_personal_hostel_bookmark_id.shift()` it until the length is < 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `watcher` on the model to remove the first item in the array.
Like so:

```html
<div id="app">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Bike" v-model="items"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Car" v-model="items"> I have a car<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle3" value="Boat" v-model="items"> I have a boat<br>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: ['Car']
  },
  watch: {
    items(newVal) {
      // Do nothing f the array is empty or already only has one value
      if (newVal.length <= 1) {
        return
      }

      // Otherwise, remove the first item in the array
      newVal.shift()
    }
  }
})
```

You can also [play with the JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/hugodesigns/jf5twzup/).